# Animate not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Here is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
        checkurl("google.com", "#google")
}); 

function setpanelToRed (panel){
    $(panel+".list-group-item-success").animate({backgroundColor: "#d9534f"}, 1000);
}
function setpanelToYellow (panel){
    $(panel+".list-group-item-success").animate({backgroundColor: "#d9534f"}, 1000);
}
function setpanelToGreen (panel){
    $(panel+".list-group-item-success").animate({backgroundColor: "#d9534f"}, 1000);
}
function checkurl (link, panel){
  var url = "/redir/"+link;
  $.ajax(url,
  {
     statusCode: {
     200: function() {
        setpanelToGreen(panel);
     },
     404: function() {
        setpanelToYellow(panel);
     },
     000: function() {
        setpanelToRed(panel);
     },
     302: function() {
        setpanelToGreen(panel);
     }
  }
});   
setTimeout ( checkurl, 5000, link, panel);
}
</script>
```

And the item it is changing looks like this:

```
<a href="google.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none"><div id="#google" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" style="background-color: #5cb85c; color: #fff"><center>google</center></div></a>
```

I have changed it to remove some sensitive things, but I use this on 2 different pages, and it works perfectly in chrome, but doesn't work in firefox/ie(most of my test site doesn't work in ie, but that doesn't matter as much to me.

Comment: It's been a while for me... but I think that animating color requires a plugin on top of the regular animate function (since it isn't a simple linear numeric increase/decrease)

Comment: I have a special one loaded up for it actually, forgot to include:<script src="/js/jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin ?